# JaCoCo missing line if return in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jacoco

[image]

As image above, I can only get 100% code coverage if all functions in my class are `void`. Whenever there is a return, line coverage will be broken.

How can I fix it?

More Information:

```java
class Result {
    String resultBody;

    public String getResultBody() {
        return resultBody;
    }
}
```

I ran `JaCoCo` via `gradle`

Comment: Provide more information: is that a JPA entity ? JaCoCo instrument the bytecode, and there may be several place (compiler, compiler' plugin, asm, ...) that create/modify your byte code. You could check with javap what's around your getter.

Comment: No, it's not JPA entity. It's just a normal class with a getter. I run JaCoCo via gradle.

Comment: Your image indicates default visibility (aka package private) while the code you've posted has public visibility. Which is it?

Comment: Also print the unit test making this coverage. You should also check the result of `javap -v -l Result.class`, especially the part regarding your method.

Comment: I use Groovy, it's public as default. 

Unittest for this coverage is just call a setter

Comment: If you use Groovy, then this is following bug in Groovy compiler that produces unreachable bytecode - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9126

Comment: And BTW please update your question to clearly indicate that this is not Java, but Groovy.

Comment: Yes, in my title, and even in tags, it's all about Groovy :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known issue of Groovy: http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9126

Thank @Godin

UPDATED: Since http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9126 is CLOSE as Fixed - but still there some case is missing.

You can track this problem here: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/884

Comment: This has broken my process for finding missed test cases.  How to find missed lines of code if every method has one line 'missed'.  Please consider voting for this apache issue to get it addressed.